# October CMS /backend not found 404 with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, content-management-system

I installed October CMS on my Nginx server, installed fine. Front end works with index.php and the style is correct. However backend does not. It just gives me a 404 page error. I've followed everything on the docs correctly, tried different sites-avaliable config files and they don't seem to work but give a 502, which I've checked the logs too and nothing in there.

This is my one3.com config file:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    root /storage/www/one3community.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    listen  443;
    ssl     on;
    ssl_certificate         /ssl_keys/one3community.com/public.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /ssl_keys/one3community.com/private.pem;
    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name www.one3community.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converted default apache .htaccess file to Nginx. Loaded into sites-available .conf file restarted nginx. Now up and running.

** Had to replace every break with last in nginx file otherwise causes file download **

Comment: Could you please add the converted nginx file?